# Sub arrays in python

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, sum, sub-array

How to print the sum of user desired subarray from a given list [1,2,3,4,5,6] using slice method in python ?

I've got success till the slice method and displaying the subarray , but I am not able to do the sum operation as it is showing error for data type of list i.e. string.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin function `sum` or do it manually by:

```
arr= []
sum= 0

for i in range(len(subarr)):

    sum+= subarr[i]
    arr.append(sum)
return arr
```